# Viewing pageviews for customvar in analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have added a custom var to my google analytcs tracking to group pages, for example:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'page-group', 'cat-technology', 3]);
```

Now I'm able to view customvar's analytics, but it only shows me visitors.

How can I display pageviews for a customvar?

Comment: what report are you in that it only shows you visitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to see the results specific to those custom vars in **any** report, you can also se a Advanced Segment and apply it to the reports:

- Click on Advanced Segments on any report, and choose + New Custom Segment
- On the Field, choose "Include" and CustomVar(Key (Your Key)), then "Containing" and finally  type in the value you are looking for ( or range, using a regex )

There you go, you can now see almost all reports containing only information about the visits marked with that Custom Var.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see a lot more than visitors in the Standard Reporting => Audience => Demographics => Custom Variables report.

This is what I see (new interface)

[image]